# How to send variable and its value to html

Tags: html, http, go

I have written a small piece of code in go

```
func loginHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println("loginHandler")
    log.Println("request url is", r.RequestURI)
    log.Println("request method", r.Method)
    requestbody, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    log.Println("request body is", string(requestbody))
    if r.Method == "POST" {
        us, err := globalSessions.SessionStart(w, r)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        us.Set("LoggedInUserID", "000000")
        w.Header().Set("Location", "/auth")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusFound)
        return
    }
    outputHTML(w, r, "static/login.html")
}
```

```html
func outputHTML(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, filename string) {
 log.Println("outputHTML")
 requestbody, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)
 log.Println("request body is", string(requestbody))
 log.Println("request body is", requestbody)
 file, err := os.Open(filename)
 if err != nil {
  http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
  return
 }
 defer file.Close()
 fi, _ := file.Stat()
 http.ServeContent(w, req, file.Name(), fi.ModTime(), file)
}
```

in this code i am redirecting to login.html . now i want to send a variable let it be some string called testvariable and its value to login.html.

Comment: How are you redirecting? outputHTML == http.Redirect() ?  If so in the redirect you two options. 1) pass the data as a URL parameter and on the backend grab the parameter, pass to the template and render.   2) Redirect to another backend endpoint, which handles all the logic, sets the data up, and renders the template. You can't pass data directly on a redirect.  Example myTemplate.ExecuteTemplate(w, "base", data). Also see the html package https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/

Comment: Please show the definition of `outputHTML` since that's the function that renders your login page.

Comment: @mkopriva, i updated my question with relevant data i guess now

Comment: Check out this [tutorial](https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/) in particular about using `html/template`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to display values in your html you can use Go's `html/template` package.

First you'll need to specify where in the html page you want your values to appear, using the `html/template` package you can do that with [template actions](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#pkg-overview).

> "Actions"--data evaluations or control structures--are delimited by
>   "{{" and "}}"

Next you'll need to drop the `http.ServeContent` function as that does not know how to render templates, instead you can use [Execute](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Execute) to display the login page together with your values.

Here's an example:

**login.html**:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>{{.MyVar}}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

**outputHTML**:

```
func outputHTML(w http.ResponseWriter, filename string, data interface{}) {
    t, err := template.ParseFiles(filename)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
        return
    }
    if err := t.Execute(w, data); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
        return
    }
}
```

And your **loginHandler**:

```
func loginHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    // do whatever you need to do

    myvar := map[string]interface{}{"MyVar": "Foo Bar Baz"}
    outputHTML(w, "static/login.html", myvar)
}
```

Read more on templates here: [html/template](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template) and for information about how to program the templates themselves, see the documentation for [text/template](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template)